# Segmentation Fault returned using strtok

Tags: c, split, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm trying to create a function in c which split strings just like split function in java or many other languages.
I made this

```
char **split(char * str, char *ch) {
  char **array = (char **)malloc((strlen(str)) * sizeof(*array));
  int i = 0;
  char *token = strtok(str, ch);
  while (token != NULL) {
    array[i++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
  }
  free(token);
  return array;
}
```

This seems to work but not always and not properly.
Let's assume we invoke this in 2 different ways:
1rst the working one:

```
int main(){
  
  while(1){
    sleep(1);
    char h = ':';
    char a[] = "test:1234";
    char ** result = split(a,&h);
    printf("%s\n",result[0]);
    printf("%s\n",result[1]);
    free(result);
  }
}
```

while the second one gives me a segmentation fault at the second while cycle:

```
int main(){
  char a[] = "test:1234";
  char h = ':';
  while(1){
    sleep(1);
    char ** result = split(a,&h);
    printf("%s\n",result[0]);
    printf("%s\n",result[1]);
    free(result);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
test
1234
test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I think this is due to a manipulation of the string index by the strtok function but I cannot understand how to fix it and exactly why it gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: strtok *modify* the string putting null char in it, you suppose the string is unchanged, so the second turn of loop *while* *a* is "test\01234" and *split* find only one result and `result[1]` is no tinitialized with an undefined behavior when you print it. An other undefined behavior is the fact you do not give a nulll terminated string as separator

Comment: What is `free(token);` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are calling `strtok` incorrectly.

`strtok` is expecting two strings, i.e. the string to split and a string of delimiters.

But you are not passing a **string** of delimiters - you a passing a pointer to a single character.

So change it like:

```
char h = ':';                  --->  char *h = ":";
```

and

```
char ** result = split(a,&h);  --->  char ** result = split(a,h);
```

Another issue with your code is that you expect it to always return at least two valid tokens. That is a bad assumption and it will fail in the second loop of your second code example.

In the first loop `a` will be changed to be the string "test" because `strtok` replaces the `':'` with a string termination character.

In the second loop there will consequently only be one token. This means that `result[1]` is not pointing to a valid token and therefore, you are not allowed to print what it is pointing to.

One way to fix that problem is to set all the `result` pointers to NULL in the function, e.g. by using `calloc` instead of `malloc` like:

```
char **array = calloc(strlen(str), sizeof(*array));
```

and then do the printing like:

```
if (result[0]) printf("%s\n",result[0]);
if (result[1]) printf("%s\n",result[1]);
```

or better:

```
int i = 0;
while(result[i])
{
    printf("%s\n",result[i]);
    ++i;
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **split(char * str, char *ch) {
  char **array = calloc(strlen(str), sizeof(*array));  // Use calloc to set
                                                       // all pointers to NULL
  int i = 0;
  char *token = strtok(str, ch);
  while (token != NULL) {
    array[i++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
  }
  return array;
}

int main(){
  char a[] = "test:1234";
  char *h = ":";
  int z = 0;
  while(z < 5){    // Just loop 5 times
    //sleep(1);
    char ** result = split(a,h);
    int i = 0;
    while(result[i])   // Print all tokens, i.e. stop when a pointer is NULL
    {
        printf("%s\n",result[i]);
        ++i;
    }    
    free(result);
    ++z;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
test
1234
test
test
test
test
```

**BTW:**

This

```
free(token);
```

is the same as

```
free(NULL);
```

It does nothing so just delete that line.

Comment: is equivalent to call with a constant char like this: char ** result = split(a,":"); or this could lead to instability problems just like the char pointer?

Comment: @Virgula ":" is a string having 2 characters, ':' then '\0', this is not the case with `&h` in your code

Comment: @Virgula Yes, you can call it like `char ** result = split(a,":");` and even `char ** result = split(a,":,;-");` The char-pointer that you pass as delimiter for `strtok` must be a string, i.e. it must be zero-terminated.

Comment: i think @bruno is right, there is much missing here. At the beginning on my PC worked but now gives again segmentation fault. let's also give a look here: https://godbolt.org/z/Kcc6an

Comment: @4386427 thank you but there is another question: your code prints only the first time the second part of the split string (1234). In the remaining, it only prints test but for every circle, I need 1234 too.

Comment: @Virgula this is the difference between your first proposal were you work on "test:1234" in all the loops and the second when you work on "test" (whatever the content after the  null char et in it)

Comment: @Virgula Exactly... Read my answer closely! What happen is that the orginal sring `a` is "test:1234" but in the first loop it is changed to just "test". You can see that by adding `printf("%s\n", a);` just before calling `split`

Comment: @Virgula Also read the comment from Bruno just above. The difference between your examples is that the first re-initialize `a` **inside** the loop while the second initializes `a` outside the loop. Consequently the first prints alternatin "test" and "1234" but the second prints "test" "1234" "test" "test" "test" .... That is what `strtok` do - change the string.

Comment: Understood. It's just how strtok works, so this function is not the best solution to reach my goal, anyway adding a ```char temp[strlen(a)];``` ```strcpy(temp,a);``` inside the loop and passing temp to the function should fix all.

Comment: @Virgula Well, if you want to do that make sure to do: `char temp[1 + strlen(a)];` as you need an extra char for the string termination

Comment: For me replacing this ```' '``` to this ```" "``` fixed the problem. I'm glad most of the work I do is in JS :P btw I hope you support Palestine too, we witness most horrible genocide.

Answer (score 1):

strtok is a bit tricky to use since it handles memory differently
from what one is used to - it modifies the string that is passed as argument returning a pointer to the substring, when strtok(NULL,..) a new pointer is returned to the buffer, if the buffer goes out of scope the pointers become invalid or if another thread is calling strtok the pointers become invalid so best is to copy the returned token to another before buffer before proceeding.

this can be achieved by allocating a memory block and then copying in
the returned value there

```
char **split(char * str, char *ch) {
  char **array = (char **)malloc((strlen(str)) * sizeof(*array));
  int i = 0;
  char *token = strtok(str, ch);
  while (token != NULL) {
    char* dupToken = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
    strcpy(dupToken, token);
    array[i++] = dupToken;
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
  }
  // free(token); // this here is wrong
  return array;
}
```

now another problem with your code is that the caller has no way of knowing
how many tokes are in the returned array so I would suggest another approach

once you hit the last token, set the next pointer to NULL before returning
array

```
char **split(char * str, char *ch) {
  char **array = (char **)malloc((strlen(str)) * sizeof(*array));
  int i = 0;
  char *token = strtok(str, ch);
  while (token != NULL) {
    char* dupToken = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
    strcpy(dupToken, token);
    array[i++] = dupToken;
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
  }
  array[i] = NULL;    
  return array;
}
```

that way when you go through the tokens you can just check the pointer

```
for (int i = 0; array[i] != NULL; ++i)
{ 
...
}
```

edit: it is then probably good to add another entry to your array so that you can handle max number of tokens + 1

```
char **array = (char **)malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(*array));
```

EDIT: changed my rather sloppy description of what happens with the pointer that is returned, it is valid as long as the original buffer passed to strtok is valid.

Comment: Interresting. Quote "... called again that pointer becomes invalid" Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @4386427 In strtok there is a static pointer which is moved every  time strtok(NULL, ... ) is called and that is what is returned. strtok modifies the string that was passed to it on the first call in every subsequent call with strtok(NULL...)

Comment: @AndersK But it does not invalidated previously returned pointers. They are all pointers to some location in the original string (except for the final NULL). **The copying is simply not needed.** The purpose of `strtok` is to transform the orginal string buffer into a number of strings and return pointers to these new strings one-by-one. The posted code will do the job but it is misleading to say that the copying is required. It isn't.

Comment: @AndersK See https://ideone.com/71a5xM It shows how the returned pointers all points into the original buffer and consistently points to the correct token. Nothing returned by `strtok` gets invalidated.

Comment: @4386427 You are right, my description was a bit sloppy, I have corrected it.